# Modify or control RPS of an external JMeter Test Plan (JMX File)

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, distributed-testing

In continuation with this ques - [Modify Thread Group of an external JMeter Test Plan (JMX File)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63468826/modify-thread-group-of-an-external-jmeter-test-plan-jmx-file)

My application will take jmx file as test plan from user and execute it. I've JMeter distributed setup at the backend of my application (1 JMeter client and multiple JMeter servers).

1. Is there a way to control/limit the RPS of this test plan?
2. Is there a way to modify RPS at runtime for this user-provided test plan (not created by us)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done without modifying the .JMX script.

1. RPS can be controller by adding i.e. [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) or [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) to the Test Plan and specifying the desired throughput there
2. RPS can be controller in the runtime by [Beanshell Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server), see [How to Change JMeter´s Load During Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-change-jmeters-load-during-runtime) article for comprehensive explanation if needed